# Get value of <li> element from value attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

I am developing a small website for a school project. On one page I iterate over an array which is populated via SQL query. The data will be displayed like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" name="id" value="36"><span class="badge">9999</span>Testval</li>
</ul>
```

The name of that `li` element is always static but the value is filled in with PHP. The value refers to the ID in the DB. I am trying to write a query for a delete statement which looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM `Kredit` WHERE ID=id;
```

The `id` should be retrieved when the user clicks the delete button on that specific li element. There will be multiple `li` elements which all have a different id. Is it possible to retrieve the id in the value attribute with PHP?

I searched on Stackoverflow for this question but all the questions were referring to the value between the li tags in my case "testval".

Comment: Could you add the complete html and where the form and delete button are setup?

Comment: if you want to do this action in  PHP you have to include your PHP code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you need Javascript to do this, jQuery code for this will loke like below. I dont see the delete button to be more specific, but i will explaine the code and hope to be clear enough for you.

```
$( "#delete" ).click(function() { // when delete is clicked
var id = $(this).attr("value");   // get id value of clicked li's delete
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        aysync: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { delete : id},
        url: "ajax.php", // cal ajax.php with ?delete=123, use $_GET['delete']
        success: function(data){
            $(this).closest('li').remove(); // if ajax is done, remove this li
        }
});
```

This example is for value id, i don't think you would like to search in DB by strings like testval instead of unique id.

Comment: But is it a good idea to store the ID in the HTML where the user could edit it? Even if it's not visible it could be changed via F12.

Comment: Agree with you, but users can edit text value too. Permissions are another issue that is not discussed in this question

Comment: Do you know of a better approach for storing the ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr` to get value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.list-group-item').click(function () {
     alert($(this).attr("value"));
   });
});
```

`value` is not a `valid attribute` for `li` but you can still get the `value` but it would be better to use `data-value`

Comment: O.P. stated that they wanted to get the `testval` part not the `value=` part

Comment: @mike510a OP never stated that.OP has clearly asked to get value part.

Comment: I guess you need to re-read the last line aslo see query where op is matcing the `id`

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You have to pass the value from users side (js) via ppost/ajax to your backend (php). If youve got sth like this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  <input name="id" id="submitter" value="00">
</form>
<li id="210">//your elem
... Another elems
<ul class="delete">Delete</ul>
</li>
```

Lets come to our js:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
Deleters=document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
 for(i=0;i<Deleters.length;i++){
 deleter=Deleters[i];
 deleter.onclick=function(){
 send(this.parentNode.id);//or .value
 //this gets the id of the parents node (the li elem)
 };
 }
 };
 function send(value){
 document.getElementById("submitter").value=value;
 document.forms[0].submit();
 }
 </script>
```

Now you need a php to handle (call it action.php):

```
<?php
$delid=$_POST["id"]
....
```